# function that returns both value and callback- how can I get both?

Tags: node.js, callback, promise, pkgcloud

I'm using [pkgcloud](https://github.com/pkgcloud/pkgcloud) to build a webservice (express based) that will manage my openstack storage. I have a problem with downloading a file.

the [pkgcloud api for download](https://github.com/pkgcloud/pkgcloud/blob/master/docs/providers/openstack/storage.md#clientdownloadoptions-functionerr-file--) is a bit wierd: it passes to the callback the error and file's metadata, and returns from the function a readable stream with the file's content:

```
client.download({
    container: 'my-container',
    remote: 'my-file'
}, function(err, result) {
    // handle the download result
})).pipe(myFile);
```

The problem I have with this is- how can I get the error, the metadata and the stream together? I need the metadata in order to set the content type for my result and obviously I need the error to know if all went well (in case the file doesn't exist, the stream is still returned- just containing an html error message, so I can't count on that for error).

I tried calling it like this:

```
router.get("/download", function (res, req) { 
 var stream = client.download(options, function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(err.status).json({'message' : 'Error downloading file from   storage: ' + err.details});
  } 
 }
 // I'd like to get the callback's err and file here somehow
 stream.pipe(res);
});
```

but the problem is that the data is piped to res before callback is called, so the callback doesn't help- it is either giving me the error too late, or not giving me the metadata. I also tried moving the stream.pipe(res) into the callback, but it does not work, cause inside the callback I can't access the result stream.

I thought of using promise for that, but how can I tell the promise to 'wait' for both the callback and the returned value? I'm trying to wrap the download function with a function that will run the download with one promise in the callback and one on the returned stream, but how can I do that?

Comment: The stream doesn't emit events with the data you need? What do you mean you can't access the stream in the callback -- why not?

Comment: @JMM -  how can I access something that returned by the function inside the callback? the stream does emit events, but not error event (in case of error, it returns a stream error message in html format)

Comment: By virtue of the fact that the callback captures the `stream` binding and the function executes synchronously. As long as it doesn't sometimes synchronously execute the callback you should be able to.

Comment: @GMM - if I access the stream from inside the callback, the file is corrupted. My guess is that the stream is not fully piped at this stage (if I debug it and by that cause a delay- it does come ok, which makes me believe it some sort of race condition)

Comment: Well, the callback is likely executing later than the line following the call to `client.download()`...